# Repositories / Lazy Loading / Persistance

Tags: design-patterns, domain-driven-design

I have some trouble with the repository pattern. Or maybe just some unclear points. For sake of these questions I have a simple example domain with two entity aggregates.

```
public class Category
{
  string Name {get;set;}
  Category Parent {get;set;}
  IList<Category> Children {get;set;}
}

public class Transaction
{
  Category Owner {get;set;}
  string Name
  ... bla bla
}
```

In this particular Domain model these two do not form a single aggregate. As such, I have two standard *IRepository* implementations for each of the two entities.

**Question One**: When dealing with validation, such as deletion of a category, a repository needs to do relational checks. Is it a common practise that repositories talk (and as such are injected with references) to other repositories and generate errors, thus keeping it neatly disconnected from the other layers or do they delegate this to the database layer?

**Question Two**: Similarly, when updating an entity (aggregate) often save/change/delete validation needs to be done on various components. Presumably this is only reasonably doable when you have a unit of work that buffers changes and only commits when all validation succeed?

**Question Three**: Loading a single category results in an entire object tree to be loaded when not using lazy loading. To limit this the only real option is to implement lazy loading and/or change tracking in your entities?

Comment: Drop repository pattern. Do not try to pick up what you cannot carry. Abstracting persistence is nearly impossible if rdbms is underneath.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For all your three questions I would recomend you to implement UnitOfWork pattern. I ususaly implement `IUnitOfWork` that is a part of my repositories. When I want to work with more then one of my repositories I inject (the same) UnitOfWork into all I want to work with (That is just one of the ways that I prefer). Then when all work is done I call Commit() on my UnitOfWork which does savechanges on entity frameworks context. UnitOfWork is **wrapper around entity frameworks context**.

**Question one:** Relational checks are done by database. If something fails entity framework will throw exception and you should handle it in you higher app layer, lets call it service layer where you work with your UnitOfWork.

**Question two:** Use UnitOfWork pattern.

**Question three:** You should use lazy loading if you dont want to load the whole object tree.

Repository:

```
    public interface IRepository<T>
{
    IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork { get; set; }
    IQueryable<T> All();
    void Delete(T item);
    void Save(T item);
    void Update(T item);
    IQueryable<T> Find(Func<T, bool> expression);
    void Attach(T item);        
}
```

UnitOfWork:

```
    public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    ObjectContext Context { get; set; }
    void Commit();
    bool LazyLoadingEnabled { get; set; }
    bool ProxyCreationEnabled { get; set; }
    string ConnectionString { get; set; }
}
```

OR here is very simle implementation of [UnitOfWork](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/06/16/using-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-with-entity-framework-4-0.aspx) pattern to get you started(Its a bit different from what i described UnitOfWork contains Repositories mine is the other way around...).

Comment: Your answer is very much tailored to the EF framework. But what if, say, my DB layer doesn't even do relational checks. Such as a simple DAL using MyISAM MySQL tables? I cannot delegate it to the EF layer. I don't even know if there would be an EF layer in the case of validation. And with seperation of concerns, should validation even -know- of the type of persistance layer?

Comment: Does your db support primary keys and foreigh keys? If not then use some else but i doubt it doesnt. All basic dabases have relational checks. May be you ment transactions?

Comment: No, but say, for example the entities are simply stored in serialized binary files. Validation if deletions are allowed, saves are allowed shouldn't be aware of the storage, right? It violated SoC.

Comment: Okey, if that is the case your repository implementation should take care of relational chcks. Then there should be higher level - a service where you can put your UnitOfWork in practice. Level which will not know anytning abour reposirory implementation.

Comment: Mmh. I am thinking about it the wrong way. There's nothing wrong about repositories talking with one another for validation sake while using some form of UoW or not .. but it would depend on the implementation of the repository. The rest of the domain doesn't care one way or another how it is taken care of. Except that it IS the repositories responsibility to keep the database valid.

Comment: Its usualy good idea that repositories talk to each other at service layer. Not injecting them among themselves.

Comment: But if repositories are not to talk amongst themselves, only at service level above the model, how do repositories make sure referential integrity is maintained when dealing with very dumb data backends?

Comment: I would do chceks within repository (yes I would reach into data of aother repositories but on low level to perform checks that would have nothing to do with crud operations of other repositories). Example: Lets say You would want to save category with new items. This would require two repositories to cooperate - this would happen on service layer within one unit of work. If it would sucseed I would do commit or rollback at the very end of service. Each repository woud do its own checks. Base on that I would raise exceptions that woud determine sucsession or failure of this transaction.

Comment: You say a repository should only do only checks that do not reach into other repositories and do your updates using services that do reach into various repositories. But that would imply storing an entity directly using the repository might lead to referential trouble when dealing with a dumb data layer. Validation would have to be in a service then?